# how i can get the senderAddress from email using download-email-attachments

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, imap

I'm using [download-email-attachments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download-email-attachments) lib to download a file from email. But i can't find a variable/method to use and save this address in a json like other email info that i do.